# question about Blandford-Znajek original paper

Tags: electromagnetism, pair-production, black-holes

I'm trying to follow the original Blandford-Znajek paper (found [here](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1977MNRAS.179..433B&data_type=PDF_HIGH&whole_paper=YES&type=PRINTER&filetype=.pdf)), and I can't find how equations 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 are obtained:

2.1 refers to *"the charge density required to ensure that $E \cdot B = 0$"*:

$$ \rho \approx \epsilon_0 \frac{a}{M^2} c B $$

2.2 refers to *"potential difference across gap of height $h$ when no charge is present"*:

$$ \Delta V \approx \frac{a}{M^2} c B h^2 $$

2.3 refers to *"energies of produced pairs in the unstable vacuum"*:

$$ \gamma \approx \Big ( \frac{h}{M} \Big )^2 \Big ( \frac{ \omega_G a }{c} \Big ) $$

the relevant page is this:

[image: relevant page]

There is some mention to a voltage over a gap $h$, a current $j$ and charge density $\rho$, but is not clear what is happening and how everything fits together. There is neither a reference to another paper or textbook where that formula is obtained, so I presume that their derivation should be really trivial and easy, but I can't figure out what that is. I look the figures in the paper, but none that clearly refers to this argument

That section also talks about how the magnetosphere is generated (see image below). Note this fragment:

> The currents that pervade the magnetosphere as sources of the magnetic
>   field are presumably carried by charged particles that are flowing
>   **outwards** at large distances

This assertion seems very confusing to me. Why "outwards"? isn't the magnetosphere caused by *infalling* accretion matter? why would anything be moving "outwards" at all?

Does anyone understand what is the geometry being described?

[image: source of the magnetosphere]

Comment: I just glanced at the Ruderman and Sutherland paper cited in the second paragraph of section 2.  It seems to mention $E\cdot B$ a lot... I would look there: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1975ApJ...196...51R

Comment: @PaulT. looking at section II of that paper, they seem to make the assumption that most of the magnetic field comes from the neutron star degenerated core. I think that assumption cannot be extrapolated as is for black holes. I wonder why Blandford/Znajek quote it as if it was relevant without further details